# Is there a better way to get class constructor augments?

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, function-pointers

So. Example that I have a lots of class, each had it own constructor. And I want a function with take the augments of the constructor and do something with it.

```
class AA {
public:
    AA(int a, float b, double c) {}
};


void someFunc() {
    // do something.
}
```

I can't get pointer of the constructor, but I can get the function pointer of class member and I just need to create a function same as the constructor in every class and pass it to this function:

```
class AA {
    public:

        AA(int a, float b, double c) {}

        void constructor(int a, float b, double c) {}
};


template<typename type, typename Cls, typename...args>
void getClassMemberInfo(type(Cls::* func)(args...))
{
    // my Example:
    ((std::cout << typeid(args).name() << "\n"), ...);
}


int main()
{
    getClassMemberInfo(&AA::constructor);
}
```

Or I can create a tuple have same augments as the construct, and my function become this:

```
class AA {
public:
    std::tuple<int, float, double> constructor;

    AA(int a, float b, double c) {}
};


template<typename Cls, typename...args>
void getClassTupleInfo(std::tuple<args...>Cls::* func)
{
    // my Example:
    ((std::cout << typeid(args).name() << "\n"), ...);
}
```

It still work fine. But I want to know is there a other way else to do this?

Comment: Constructors indeed do not have an address, or signature, or return type for that matter. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: never mind, I realize that I just ask opinion for a better solution.